# Emotion.js how to do composition / conditional styling in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, emotion

https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/tree/master/packages/native

gives example

```
    style={css`
      border-radius: 10px;
    `}
```

However, I can't figure out how I can do `composition` as done in https://emotion.sh/docs/composition with react-native

```
    <div css={[danger, base]}>
```

Nor I can't do conditional styling as done in https://emotion.sh/docs/styled

```
const Button = styled.button`
  color: ${props =>
    props.primary ? 'hotpink' : 'turquoise'};
`
```

Even if I could do, they use two different methods one using `css` one using `styled` . How can I get the two at the same time with react-native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: How to do `composition` in `emotion/native` in React Native?

It's really simple all you need to is use style property like so:

```
const style1 = css`
  font-size: 40px;
`

const color = css`
  color: red;
`

// And then in your component you can pass the all your style objects 
// in an array to style property
<Text style={[fontSize, color]}>Hello world</Text>
```

Question 2: Conditional style in `emotion/native` in React Native?

```
const Description = styled.Text`
    font-size: ${props =>  props.fontSize !== undefined ? props.fontSize : "40px"};
  color: hotpink;
`

<Description fontSize={"60px"}>
Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable url.
</Description>
```

Here's a working exampe as a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@fayeed/joyous-nachos)